# After tar fails the script exits without handling the error

Tags: bash, shell-script, tar

So, I have a backup script that looks like:

```
tar -cf "${BACKUP_TAR}" "${LATEST_SUCCESSFUL_BACKUP}" 2>&1 | tee -a "${LOG_FILE}"

  local PACKING_EXITCODE=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
  if [ ${PACKING_EXITCODE} -eq 0 ]; then 
    logging 'Packing successful'
  else
    logging "ERROR: Packing failed! ERROR: ${PACKING_EXITCODE}. Disk space?"
    df -h 2>&1 | tee -a "${LOG_FILE}"
    logging "Check the log file: ${LOG_FILE}"
    set_lockfile 'destroy'
    backup_remove_package
    exit 1
  fi
```

`logging` is a function to log properly into my log file.

```
logging () {
  local now="$(date)"
  local logfile=$2
  local logfile=${logfile:-$LOG_FILE}
  cat <<< "${now} $@" | tee -a "${logfile}"
}
```

set_lockfile "destroy"` is a function that removes my lock file.

```
set_lockfile () {
  local lockfile_action=$1
  local lockfile=$2
  local lockfile=${lockfile:-$LOCK_FILE}

  if [ "${lockfile_action}" == "create" ]; then
    #...
  elif [ "${lockfile_action}" == "destroy" ]; then
   destroy_lockfile $lockfile
  else
    logging 'ERROR: Wrong argument for locking file: use create or destroy'
    exit 1
  fi
}

destroy_lockfile () {
  local lockfile=$1

  if [ ! -f ${lockfile} ]; then
    logging "WARNING: Lockfile ${lockfile} not found!"
  else
    logging "Removing lockfile ${lockfile}"
    rm -f "${lockfile}"
  fi
}
```

`backup_remove_package` is a function to remove any temporary files created.

I experience a failed packing due to a disk full, expected behavior as you can guess for the `df -h`.

The interesting thing is the backup log. It states:

```
tar: /tmp/backup/20180827T223001.tar: Wrote only 4096 of 10240 bytes
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      788G  788G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        3.9G   60K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Which means, `tar` failed, then it went through the `if` condition, somehow skipped the `logging "ERROR: ..."`, executed the `df -h` and died. skipping the rest.

Somehow looks like is skipping any function but running the commands.

The backup is called from a `cron.d` file.
I have NOT set `set -e`, so no exit on error is done.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to know the exact problem for sure but some guesses: your `logging` method is not robust enough in case the filesystem is full (note that you do not handle failed `logging` call), something goes wrong with your functions but the `stderr` is redirected to blackhole or somewhere you're not looking at and as a result, you do not catch the actual error message you need.

Comment: I "agree", edited to add the code, but if logging is not working, why is `df` working? Also `set_lockfile` only removes a file, the same than `backup_remove_package` and neither of them works.

Comment: Are you sure the remaining lock file and $BACKUP are from the same run of the script as the one that wrote that text to the log file? Check their last modification time.

Answer (score 3):

Your script appears to work as expected. The output of `df` has clearly made it to `$LOG_FILE` and `exit 1` is causing the script to exit.

We don't know what your `logging` command does, but AFAICT, it is not meant to write to `$LOG_FILE`. If it were, it would be a bit silly to write *Check the log file: ${LOG_FILE}* there.

### Edit

Now that you've posted the `logging` function, I can see it uses a here-string (`<<<`).

In `bash`, here-strings and here-documents are implemented using temporary files (in `$TMPDIR` or `/tmp` if `$TMPDIR` is not defined). If that was the filesystem that was full, that would explain why `logging` didn't output anything.

```
$ sudo mount -o size=1 -t tmpfs empty /mnt/1
$ yes > /mnt/1/fill-up
yes: standard output: No space left on device
$ TMPDIR=/mnt/1 bash -c 'cat <<< test'
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

Instead of:

```
local now="$(date)"
cat <<< "${now} $@" | tee -a "${logfile}"
```

Just use:

```
printf '%(%FT%T%z)T %s\n' -1 "$*"
printf '%(%FT%T%z)T %s\n' -1 "$*" >> "$logfile"
```

Or:

```
local msg
printf -v msg '%(%FT%T%z)T %s' -1 "$*"
printf '%s\n' "$msg"
printf '%s\n' "$msg" >> "$logfile"
```

(assumes `$IFS` is unset or starts with space)

That saves the temporary file, but also avoids forking any process or executing any external command (which could also fail under some pathological conditions) (and give you a more useful date format, feel free to adapt).

More generally, a system with a full /tmp and /var filesystem is a crippled system, you can expect a lot of things not to work properly.

Here, you're lucky you've got logs at all. Disk space for files is allocated in blocks (typically 4K on ext4), which is probably why you got some output into `$LOG_FILE (as the last block was allocated before the file system got full).

Scripts run by cron have their stdout and stderr on a temporary file as well (then cron tries to send an email with their content if they're not empty). So any of the commands could have their `write(1, ...)` or `write(2, ...)` fail as well (with ENOSPC error) which could cause them to misbehave or exit early if they consider it a fatal error.

Comment: No, it does not. 
`logging` is a wrapper for the log file to add a date and pipe the output to both stdin and the log. It writes the entire log until there, so `logging` is working.
The message "check the log file" is just in case someone is reading the syslog or cronjob.
Same for `set_lockfile`, works until this block of code. And the same for `backup_remove_package`, that should remove the /tmp/backup folder and when it fails with this condition it doesn't remove it either.

Comment: @TanisDLJ, still, it seems more likely that `logging` failed to write the error message to the log file (possibly because it exited earlier because of the disk being full). In any case, I'd have a look at that `logging`  command.

Comment: @TanisDLJ, `<<<` creates a temporary file. If `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` is on the fs that was full, that would explain why `logging` didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! But still does not explain why it didn't removed the lock-file and so :(. That's literally an rm -f.

Comment: @TanisDLJ we'd need to see the code of those functions.

Comment: They are as I described, a single "if the file exist, remove it".
The only thing that might be failing is that the functions are calling "logging" before taking the action:
`logging "Removing ${BACKUP}"
  if [ -f "${BACKUP}" ];then
    rm -rf "${BACKUP}"
 fi`
 Might be that because logging is failing, that makes fail the entire function?

Comment: @TanisDLJ, not with that code AFAICT.  What does `set_lockfile` do?

Comment: It is edited already

Answer (score 1):

There is a high probability that the problem is that

```
PACKING_EXITCODE=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

is no valid shell code but something that is `bash` specific.

Cron calls commands with `/bin/sh` that differs from `bash`.

You could let your script start with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and make the script executable using `chmod +x scriptname` to make sure the `bash` specific code is executed by `bash` and not by the default shell.

Comment: If it wasn't `bash`, the OP would probably get a syntax error about `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` or an error about the `local` command not being found. AFAIK, only bash and pdksh (or zsh in ksh emulation) support `local`, arrays and 0 indices. Also clearly the right branch of the if condition has been picked here as `df` was run.

Comment: The script is in bash, as @StéphaneChazelas stated. Good point tho, but is not the case. Thanks anyway!